# Getting an infinite loop from set function in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to display a `div` with the class `loader` only while a PDF page is loading.

It works, but somehow the function `this.displayPage(pdf,1)` is getting looped over.

After `renderPage(page)` is called, it goes back to `didRender() > this.displayPage(pdf,1)`.

This only happens when I use `set(this, 'pageIsRendering', false/true)` so I'm thinking my problem might have to do with this.

I tried debugging my code but I don't understand what's creating the loop.

I am using PDFJS library to display the PDF document.

Here is my component.js code

```
  pageisRendered: true,
  pageIsRendering: false,

  didRender() {
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
    set(this, 'setPageValueInput', document.querySelector('.set-page-value'));
    let pdfDoc = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.url).then(pdf => {
      this.displayPage(pdf, 1);
      this.shownPdf = pdf;
      document.querySelector('.total-page-number').value = this.shownPdf.numPages;
    });
  },

  displayPage(pdf, num) {
    set(this, 'pageIsRendering', true);
    pdf.getPage(num).then(page => {
      if (this.pageisRendered) {
        this.pageisRendered = false;
        this.renderPage(page);
      }
    });
  },

  renderPage(page) {
    let scale = this.pdfScale; // render with global pdfScale variable
    let canvas = document.querySelector('.pdf-canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    let renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext).then(() => {
      this.pageisRendered = true;
      set(this, 'pageIsRendering', false);
    });
  },
```

Here is my html code

```
<div class="pdf-container ">
    <div class="canvas-container">
        {{#if pageIsRendering}}
          <div class="loader">
            {{loading-spinner isLoading="true"}}
          </div>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `displayPage` will call `renderPage` which causes a render which will trigger `didRender` again most likely therefore causing infinite loop.

I think you just need a single flag to track if the page is rendered. If it is, then don't trigger `didRender` again. Alternatively you should consider using another event instead of `didRender` such as `init`.

```
  pageisRendered: false,

  didRender() {
    if (this.pageisRendered) {
        return;
    }

    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
    set(this, 'setPageValueInput', document.querySelector('.set-page-value'));
    let pdfDoc = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.url).then(pdf => {
      this.displayPage(pdf, 1);
      this.shownPdf = pdf;
      document.querySelector('.total-page-number').value = this.shownPdf.numPages;
    });
  },

  displayPage(pdf, num) {
    pdf.getPage(num).then(page => {
        this.renderPage(page);
    });
  },

  renderPage(page) {
    let scale = this.pdfScale; // render with global pdfScale variable
    let canvas = document.querySelector('.pdf-canvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    let renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext).then(() => {
      set(this, 'pageisRendered ', true);
    });
  },
```

Comment: So using your code and using a unless instead of if in my handlebars got rid of the loop and it works for the first page, but I need the loader to happen everytime that I call displayPage() since I have a next and previous button and I want the user to know that the page is loading everytime they navigate to a new page. This is why I had two different flags and was setting pageIsRendering at true at the beginning of displayPage(). Also, using init() does not work, my component does not render with init().

Comment: Also, why does render() cause a didRender() only when I use set() to set a variable? My code works fine when I am not trying to add the loader.

Comment: I don't have the entire context of code but how about restarting the flag to `pageisRendered` false before calling `displayPage` again? The reason you code infinite loops is because `pageisRendered` never stays false in your code as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you look at my original code, I am setting `pageisRendered` to false before calling `this.renderPage()` in the `displayPage()` function. Is that not okay? I was under the impression my logic was sound since I need to make sure that the page is rendered before being displayed otherwise if the user click too fast on the nextPage button the page is not rendered correctly and my code as it is right now fixes that.

Comment: Does `this.pageisRendered = false;` actually set it safely? Don't you need to use `set(...)` function?

Comment: Your hint to use another event was the right one. `init()` was not working but looking at the doc I found `didInsertElement()` which does not re-render and now everything works fine! Thank you!